# I am trying to merge two items from two differnt lists

Tags: python

I am trying to merge two items from two different lists that are both strings, and create another variable which contains the first item, followed by the scecond item by just a space, instead of a comma and quoteation marks

```
['3', '♥', 'Ace', '♠']
```

this is what im getting right now and im trying to get something more like

```
3 ♥ Ace ♠
```

Thanks

```
AllCards = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack(10)", "Queen(10)", "King(10)"]
Suits = ["♣", "♦", "♥", "♠"]

def generate_card():
    global actualcurrentcard
    currentcard = str(random.choice(AllCards))
    currentsuit = str(random.choice(Suits))
    actualcurrentcard = [currentcard, currentsuit]
    FinalCard = " ".join(actualcurrentcard)
```

im trying to make the FinalCard variable be
3 ♥ Ace ♠
instead of it being seperated by commas, sorry for the confusion im not really sure how to explain it any better

when i run the code i get

```
['Queen(10)', '♥', '10', '♠']
```

Comment: Are you looking for `' '.join(yourlist)`?

Comment: @JNevill ive tried this but because im trying to merge two items from diffrent lists i cant do " ".join(list1, list2) as it give me and error, is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: I don't see two lists in your question. I see a single list with the desired result being that of the join method of a string. Can you clarify your question with better sample and desired results?

Comment: ive updated it hopefully explaining my problem a bit better

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have the list of strings stored into a variable,

```
myList = ["3" , "♥" , "Ace" , "♠"]
```

Python has a method called ".join()" that allows you to turn a list of strings into one string.

```
myString = ' '.join(myList)

#output: myString = "3 ♥ Ace ♠"
```

If the lists are not already combined, just do

```
list3 = list1 + list2
```

to combine them